# Single Page Application using Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-page-application, pjax

I am using django-easy-pjax for making a Single-Page-Application:

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/static/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/static/js/jquery.pjax.js' %}"></script>

{% block side%}
It is {% now "c" %} 
<br><br>
<a href="/uu/">Next Page</a>
<br/></br>
{%endblock side%}


{%block main%}
{%endblock main%}
```

1.html:

```
{% extends "base.html"|pjax:request %}
{%block main%}
If time doesnot change Easy pjax is working
{%endblock main%}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
  return render_to_response('base.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def index1(request):
  return render_to_response('1.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
    (r'^pjax/$', 'app_name.views.index'),
    (r'^uu/$', 'app_name.views.index1'),
```

But when I click on the next page the time url changes,content gets loaded but time also changes that means `easy-pjax` is not working.What correction should I make in my code?I have added pjax_base.html template in template dir. But what should be the content of pjax_base.html?Do I need to configure anything else like HTTP header on the server side?If yes how?

Comment: You should probably use a JavaScript debugger to examine the code the Django plugin is generating.

Comment: make sure the browser supports pushstate http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

Comment: @mabdrabo The browser supports pushstate.I demo works well in my browser https://easy-pjax.herokuapp.com/page-1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using django-easy-pjax was a bad idea. To make a SPA using django , REST frameworks should be used. I switched to `[Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I am using Django+ DjangoRESTFramework + AngularJS for SPA using Django

`

Comment: For serving Django REST framework with Angular as a SPA, you might be interested in the [django-spa package](https://github.com/metakermit/django-spa). Full disclosure – I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) and [django-htmx](https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) into your Django project.

`django-htmx` works with the `HTMX` JS library to make it simple for your views to return only the HTML that will be changing. `HTMX` allows you to target any element (such as `<main>` or `<body>`) to “swap” the previous (if any) content within said element w/ the content returned from your called view.

For more info, see this [example](https://htmx-django.herokuapp.com/blog/project-1-to-do-app).